# How to send a direct message when bot is ready

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot send me a dm when it's ready:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready when you are")
    print("I am running on: " + bot.user.name)
    print("With the ID: " + bot.user.id)
    await bot.send_message(discord.PrivateChannel(4803), "Ready", tts=True)
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can just tell it to send a message to you, using your id (ids in discord.py 0.16 are strings by the way, not integers).  If you have to reuse this code somewhere else,  other bots won't necessarily be able to access the private channel between you and this bot.  Something like:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready when you are")
    print("I am running on: " + bot.user.name)
    print("With the ID: " + bot.user.id)
    owner = await bot.get_user_info("Your ID")
    await bot.send_message(owner, "Ready", tts=True)
```

Comment: got this error 
    discord.errors.InvalidArgument: Destination must be Channel, 
    PrivateChannel, User, or Object. Received generator

Comment: @SachaTerry Oops, `get_user_info` is a coroutine, and must be `await`ed.

Comment: @SachaTerry I changed the code in my answer.   Just add `await` in front of the call to `bot.get_user_info`