# Bot DM's me when ready

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I want my bot to send a message in dm when he starts, using discord.py.
I tried this, that i have seen here, but it didn't work

```
async def on_ready():
  owner = await get_user_info('My ID')
  await bot.send_message(owner, 'Ready!', tts=false)
```

Comment: What's `get_user_info`??

Comment: that's what I saw here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49842851/how-to-send-a-direct-message-when-bot-is-ready?newreg=9fcfacdc5cc443e0a6885d4d54fbf417

Answer (score 5):

The code you're using is really outdated, there's no such method as `bot.send_message` and `get_user_info`. Also IDs are integers, not strings. Rewriting the code to the newest version should look like this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    owner = bot.get_user(319963626108878848)
    await owner.send("Ready!", tts=True)
```

Comment: gave this error:

File \"main.py\", line 48, in on_ready
    await owner.send('Ready!',tts=True)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: Did you enable intents?

Comment: Yep, intents are enabled

Comment: Yep
# Intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()
# The bot
bot = commands.Bot(prefix, intents = intents)

Comment: You need member intents

Comment: You could make it `intents = discord.Intents.all()` for testing and after that specify the exact intents you need.